# copy a line with specific pattern and paste it below in unix without opening a file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a specific requirement.

I have file:

```
some text

 . . . . .

 . . . . .

**todo: owner comments . . . .** 

... .

sometext
```

Now I want the output like:

```
some text

 . . . . .

 . . . . .

**todo: owner comments . . . .** 

**owner: todo comments . . . .** 

... .
   .

sometext
```

I want to grep for **todo** and copy that line and paste it below with above modification.
Can it be possible without opening a file... like sed,awk command ??

Thanks and Regards,
Dharak

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're asking. You just want to add the `owner: <todo comments>` line below any of the todo lines?

Comment: A. there are multiple modes to opening a file. Using grep "opens" a file for reading. Maybe you mean you don't need/want to "open the file for writing/update". B. Do you really mean for your file to have a blank-line between each line of text?  C.  "I want to grep for todo and copy that line and paste it below ", now I think you're asking to edit a file, and if you want to save that change, then  you need to "open the file for writing". Please update your Q, rather than responding in the comments. Good luck.

Comment: Are you expecting people to write some code for you here? Because that's not what Stack Overflow is for - it's a site for programmers to help with programming problems. If you need someone to write code for you, you might want to consider hiring a programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean is opening the file in an editor.  Here is an awk script you can tailor for your needs.

```
$ awk '/\*\*todo:/{print; print "**owner: todo ... ";next}1' file 
some text

 . . . . .

 . . . . .

**todo: owner comments . . . .** 
**owner: todo ... 

... .

sometext
```

you can save the output to a temp file and move over to your original file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually my concern not opening file and use script. I was looking for some regex.
I found one:
s/^\s*(\w+)\W+(\w+)/\\$2 \\$1/; # Flip First 2 words with 
I can use it twice and I got the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(**todo: owner comments\)\(.*\)/\1 \2  \
>   **owner: todo comments \2/g' filename
```

1. Patterns matched and replaced
2. New line is inserted manually by placing an enter after '\' at end of first line
3. '>' will come automatically pointing for the next characters to be inserted

Comment: Thanks for the answer...
I used
 s/^\s*(\w+)\W+(\w+)/\\$2 \\$1/; # Flip First 2 words